# Issue with get_absolute_url. Error Caught ViewDoesNotExist

Tags: python, mysql, django

I'm working through Practical Django Proects and I'm stuck. I receive error:

> Caught ViewDoesNotExist while rendering: Tried tagged_objects_list in module tagging.views. Error was: 'module' object has no attribute 'tagged_objects_list'.

The error goes away if I change all of the "object" in entry_archive.html to "entry", except object.get_absolute_url. Then I click on "Read Full Entry" and it redirects to /weblog/ rather than the absolute URL. Oddly enough, if I leave all "object" references as "object" and change the line to entry.get_absolute_url, the error goes away but the above /weblog/ redirect still occurs.

/cms/urls.py:

```
url(r'^weblog/', include('coltrane.urls.entries')),
```

/coltrane/urls/entries.py

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
from coltrane.models import Entry

# define entry_info_dict used for generic view
entry_info_dict = {
    'queryset': Entry.objects.all(),
    'date_field': 'pub_date',
}

# Generic Views URL Patterns
urlpatterns = patterns('django.views.generic.date_based',
    # Weblog index - Generic View
    url(r'^$', 'archive_index', entry_info_dict, 'coltrane_entry_archive_index'),
    # Archive year - Generic View
    url(r'^(?P<year>\d{4})/$', 'archive_year', entry_info_dict,      'coltrane_entry_archive_year'),
    # Archive month - Generic View
    url(r'^(?P<year>\d{4})/(?P<month>\w{3})/$', 'archive_month', entry_info_dict, 'coltrane_entry_archive_month'),
    # Archive day - Generic View
    url(r'^(?P<year>\d{4})/(?P<month>\w{3})/(?P<day>\d{2})/$', 'archive_day', entry_info_dict, 'coltrane_entry_archive_day'),
    # Weblog detail - Generic View
    url(r'^(?P<year>\d{4})/(?P<month>\w{3})/(?P<day>\d{2})/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$', 'object_detail', entry_info_dict, 'coltrane_entry_detail'),
)
```

entry_archive.html content:

```
<div id="contentarea">
    {% block content %}
        {% for object in latest %}
            <h2>{{ object.title }}</h2>
            <p>Published on {{ object.pub_date|date:"F j, Y" }}</p>
            {% if object.excerpt_html %}
                {{ object.excerpt_html|safe }}
            {% else %}
                {{ object.body_html|truncatewords_html:"50"|safe }}
            {% endif %}
            <p><a href="{{ object.get_absolute_url }}">Read full entry</a></p>
            <br>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endblock %}
</div>
```

absolute url for Entry in models.py:

```
def get_absolute_url(self):
    return ('coltrane_entry_detail', (), { 'year': self.pub_date.strftime("%Y"),
                                          'month': self.pub_date.strftime("%b").lower(),
                                          'day': self.pub_date.strftime("%d"),
                                          'slug': self.slug })
get_absolute_url = models.permalink(get_absolute_url)
```

I've seen similar issues posted while searching, but most of those seemed to be resolved by the url for weblog being weblog/$' and that is not the case for me. Just to be sure I've attempted changing the first url in coltrane/urls/entries.py to url(r'^' rather than url(r'^$' and I still get the same issue.

Thanks

Comment: It sounds like an exception is being supressed and you are simply reloading the page when you click a link. When you look at the source, does the `<a href=` actually contain a link or is it empty? i.e. `<a href=>`

Comment: The error doesn't have anything to do with `get_absolute_url`. You seem to have tried called a function or attribute called `tagged_objects_list` somewhere

Comment: I'm pretty sure permalink doesn't raise exceptions

Comment: Thanks all. Pastylegs do you want to throw that in as an answer so I can accept it? It ended up being an import of tagged_objects_list that was supposed to be tagged_object_list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error doesn't have anything to do with get_absolute_url. You seem to have tried called a function or attribute called tagged_objects_list somewhere

Comment: Thanks again. And to reiterate, it ended up being an import of tagged_objects_list that was supposed to be tagged_object_list

Answer (score 2):

You're not supposed to call `reverse()` in a `models.permalink` -- just return the tuple.

`return reverse(...)` should be `return (...)`

Comment: Crap. I left that in there. That was a suggestion from another post. Sorry, I will edit it out.

Comment: I've added the error that I receive after removing Reverse. Thanks.

Comment: @Dan, you should dig into the new exception, as that's a different problem. When you use `reverse` anywhere, all urls have to work because django runs through every url item. It's rather frustrating if you haven't used reverse in a while and you have a load of errors!